# Off-topic boot loader/firmware questions not being closed

Tags: discussion, scope

Some bootloader/firmware tags ([grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub), [efi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efi), [uefi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uefi)) are somewhat overrun by questions about how to configure boot menus, install Linux, boot a kernel and so on...

I flag them off-topic when I come across them, but I'm perceiving some lack of clarity regarding what constitutes on-topic (or simply lack of moderator love) here since I'm now up at 10 active flags.

Probably, a lot of moderators look at the tags and figure they may not have much to bring to the topic, but really - many of these questions are very clearly off-topic "how do I install?"/"how do I configure?", and those are the ones that need to go away.

How can the situation be improved?

Comment: Questions are closed by the *community*. And there are lot of questions in the queue waiting to be closed. It is a serious problem, we're still begging the Stack Exchange folks to give us more tools to deal with the influx of low-quality and off-topic questions.

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks and understood. But specifically for these tags, the "active" flags just keep building up. Flags on other tags I frequent tend to be either accepted or rejected within a few weeks.

Comment: Yeah, they are probably a corner case. I'll bet there are a bunch of people who look at them and go, "Well, I'm not sure, I don't know enough about these things to tell whether they're programming-related or not!" So they skip, which is what they're supposed to do, of course. But it doesn't help to get them closed. Crowd-sourcing the effort on Meta is the right thing to do, we eat bad questions for breakfast.

Comment: I can't act on flags but if someone closevoted a bunch of those questions which are easy indentifiable with a tag leave a message in the [SO Close Vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and some of us will help to take care of them...

Comment: The problem is your perspective; **old** unclosed questions aren't really a harm unless someone foolishly yanks them up the page with trivial edits, while some of them are on topic, and no small number have answers which are useful for challenges encountered during development work.

Comment: *New* unclosed questions became *old* unclosed questions when no one acted on the off-topic flags. Lots of off-topic questions lying around can confuse new users on what is on-topic. How to open a can without a can opener can be a problem encountered during development work - it does not make it relevant for Stackoverflow. However, situation has greatly improved after the above request.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with those that are really about programing like [Simple kernel won't boot in GRUB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14311761/792066) which is a "I'm building my kernel with this source code but it doesn't work"-kind of question. This is fine.

There are some that are potentially on topic on SU/UL that are not strictly about programming but about the bootloader itself, and can be migrated since they are not crap (case point https://stackoverflow.com/q/23916556/792066). Those are to be flagged for migration. Please, make sure you hop in their respective chat rooms beforehand to ask if they would want those questions.

Comment: On the first example I agree - but it is not representative for the questions on the GRUB tag asked this year. The second one is to me on-topic - it is about understanding the source code layout and relationships, which would certainly be off-topic for SU and most likely for UL.