# Tags in need of constant attention

Tags: discussion, tags, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts, quality-improvement

How do we cope with tags which continuously attract off-topic content?

An example is the [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) tag which was picked up in this related question:

[Off-topic boot loader/firmware questions not being closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256471/off-topic-boot-loader-firmware-questions-not-being-closed)

However, there seems to be a more systemic underlying problem which IMHO is not particularly well served by individual users proposing cleanups here on Meta every once in a while.

Tags like [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian) [centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centos) [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta) will inevitably accrue support questions about the respective platforms.  They make sense as qualifiers on Stack Overflow ("my [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) question is about C on Windows") but newcomers will post questions about the topic itself (and if they are conscientious and try to do their homework, what they see when they open the tag's page will appear to confirm their assumption that asking here for support will be okay!)

Tags which receive enough visitors will collect a fair amount of closed questions (witness [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub)) but fringe tags like [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta) will be on the verge of collapse under the load, and close votes there will appear to be squandered a lot of the time (the vote will expire before it racks up enough seconds to actually close the question).

Periodic campaigns by the close vote squad are better than nothing, of course; but I would hope to solicit ideas for innovative new mechanisms for controlling this problem.  Could these tags be somehow marked as secondary tags, for example?

Comment: Maybe something like a "Likely to contain crap" review queue? May I then suggest also adding tags like `regex`?

Comment: Perhaps a friendly hint about what is on topic and not when you enter the tag? Sort of like you get a box with tips if you enter the SQL tag?

Comment: Can't repro the SQL popup but it seems like a good starting point. Here is some background: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#274634

Comment: [tag:seo] is a well of suck.

Comment: @pnuts I [brought it up yesterday](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25684206#25684206) but the immediate response was to post on meta.  I'm in the wrong time zone to have longer meaningful discussions with the regulars there, I'm afraid.

Comment: [tag:cisco] is one of the fringe tags that get populated with IOS, PIX and ASA config questions which have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Anders Would you please post that as an answer? It has been suggested by multiple reviewers but you were the first one to bring it up.  I was hoping to get at least some brainstorming replies but it's not looking like it's happening, so your suggestion appears to be the closest thing to a conclusion we can reach at this point.

Comment: @tripleee An answer is delivered, as ordered.

Comment: At one point I was thinking of adding a queue for questions which historically performed very bad (ie, X% closed, deleted and/or unanswered), but in those cases we should just reject those questions more strongly.

Comment: [tag:boot] and [tag:kali-linux] are related too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most people are not posting these questions because they want to willfully disregard the rules. They do it because they don't know what is on topic or not. The line can sometimes be blurry, and if you are a new user it is not very easy to know.

So perhaps a friendly hint about what is on topic and not when you enter the tag would help? Sort of like you get a box with tips if you enter the SQL tag. The box could say something like this:

> Please note that only questions related to how you use X in a programming context is on topic for this site. For other questions, use our sister site Y.

Or perhaps it could say something else more tailored for the specific tag.

Answer (score 8):

The main problem is that users, especially new users, doesn't [seem to read](http://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/) or at least have the habit to dismiss any blocking
dialog you put in their face to keep them from achieving what they're up to.

I don't like the idea of secondary tags (or any kind of tag hierarchy for that matter) because it rules out any other use of such tags.

I do like the feature of [tag assistants](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)
and maybe one feature request could be to show one when a tag is added if the tag excerpt starts with **DO NOT USE**.

One other option might be to throw posts that contain **do not use** tags in the triage/first posts queue no matter what, with an indicator on it about the suspicous tag.
The outcome of the review will either be a better tag (due to retagging) or extra close votes/flags.

I noticed that some of the excerpts are not very clear about the wrong use of the tag. For example [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows):

> Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems developed by Microsoft. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific behavior. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting Windows are off-topic.

why not:

> Do not use this tag for questions about using or troubleshooting Windows, those are off-topic. Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems developed by Microsoft. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific programming behavior.

These kind of measures will help in fixing the pr0blam up-front.

Leaves us with a bunch of question in low-traffic tags that gather low-quality off-topic stuff over time.

Apart from attracting more users to regularly [close/down] vote in that tag we could have a specific Close Vote Event, facilitated by the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room. A name for these events can be [*CV support-hungry tags*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25737793#25737793)
but not everybody is convinced yet that this should be a regular event. But I'm open to give it a test run if my fellow room owners agree.

I have [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/364844) that can be used as a tag feed for those events but none of the tags mentioned by you seem to come forward. Otherwise we call the tags out individually.

Comment: I've been wondering if we could have a 'bot watch for new questions on grey-listed tags, ala SmokeDetector.

Comment: You mean the rss feed for questions?

Comment: As it turns out, YES! Exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for the SEDE fu!  [Here is the last 90 days](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/365279/470725/tags-with-many-expired-close-votes-last-90-days) which is probably a more useful metric going forward.

Comment: And [here are a few of the ones I picked out](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/365281/470728/support-hungry-tags-subjective-pick), all time.